# Foreach echo without empty variable values

Tags: arrays, variables, foreach, var

I´d like to use `foreach` to echo all images-path, but when a variable is empty `$bild_5` than shouldn't display any HTML code around.

My code:

```
<html>

<?php

// var
$url    = "http://www.URL/assets/";

$bild_1 = $url . "bild-1.jpg"; 
$bild_2 = $url . "bild-2.jpg"; 
$bild_3 = $url . "bild-3.jpg"; 
$bild_4 = $url . "bild-4.jpg"; 
$bild_5 = ""; 

// array
$bilder = array ("$bild_1", "$bild_2", "$bild_3", "$bild_4", "$bild_5");
?>

<ul>
    <!-- foreach / Template -->
    <?php foreach($bilder as $bild) { ?>    

        <li><img src="<?php echo $bild; ?>"</li>

    <?php } ?>
</ul>

</html>
```

---

### HTML-OUTPUT

```
<html>

<ul>                
   <li><img src="http://www.URL/assets/bild-1.jpg"</li>
   <li><img src="http://www.URL/assets/bild-2.jpg"</li>
   <li><img src="http://www.URL/assets/bild-2.jpg"</li>
   <li><img src="http://www.URL/assets/bild-4.jpg"</li>
   <li><img src=""</li>    // Don´t display this HTML code; ( $bild_5 = ""; )
</ul>

</html>
```

Thanks for your help
Ogni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `continue` to skip

```
<?php foreach($bilder as $bild) { ?>   
       <?php if (empty($bild)) continue; ?> 

        <li><img src="<?php echo $bild; ?>"</li>

<?php } ?>
```

I would also recommend that you use the alternate syntax for control structures when you mix PHP and HTML. It's easier to read

```
<?php foreach($bilder as $bild) : ?>    

        <li><img src="<?php echo $bild; ?>"</li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Reference - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 1):

Either use continue; as stated above, or simply let `array_filter($bilder);` run before your foreach